# angularjs ui-select not working in safari and firefox

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I'm working on an angularjs app, it uses `ui-select` but it only works on chrome.
 I don't provide code because it works well in a plunker.
Have you ever see this kind of behaviour, i'm suspecting a conflict with another angular module.
Here is the list of modules that i am using.

```
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'ui.router',
'pascalprecht.translate',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.select',
'ngLodash',
'ngIntlTelInput',
'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect',
'AxelSoft',
'ngFileUpload',
'toastr',
'tmh.dynamicLocale'
```

Comment: Share plunker link

Comment: Share your code

Comment: I use the same code that the ui-select example provides, i also test the js-custom-select module and it doesnt work either in my app but it works in a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/WiyHljAtyq1MN9IXmfyk